Installing Ubuntu 20 on a current PC with Ubuntu 24
I have a machine already running Ubuntu 24.04 but I noticed that it is giving a load to my PC as it is a dual core with 6gb ram and 500gb storage. I want to downgrade to Ubuntu 20. I downloaded the Ubuntu 20 created a bootable using Startup Disk Creator. I have changed boot priority and selected the bootable usb drive and when the PC restarts it is going to GNU GRUb where i see Ubuntu which means the already installed Ubuntu will run, Memory Test, Advanced Options which shows the recovery options, Windows Boot Manager. I want to install Ubuntu 20 and I am not seeimg the installation wizard

Are you SURE that "Ubuntu" on the LiveUSB leads to the installed 24.04 system? The read-only LiveUSB GRUB has no knowledge of what's on your hard drive.

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
